# I cannot log in the Chainlink GUI

Tags: kubernetes, helm3, chainlink

I am using this helm chart

https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/vulcanlink/chainlink

I managed to launch and connect Chainlink node with Postgres, with these values

```
config:
  # Login Info
  ROOT: /chainlink
  API_LOGIN: |
    API_EMAIL=admin@admin.com
    API_LOGIN=admin
  WALLET_PASSWORD: "9xMR9PN7CTk6Axs" # a random test password based on chainlink's demands
  # HTTP Security
  ALLOW_ORIGINS: "*"
  SECURE_COOKIES: "false"
  CHAINLINK_PORT: "6688"
  CHAINLINK_TLS_PORT: "0"
  # Database
  DATABASE_TIMEOUT: "0"
  DATABASE_URL: postgresql://chainlink:chainlink@pgdb-postgresql:5432/chainlink?sslmode=disable
  # Ethereum
  ETH_URL: wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws/v3/somerandomnumber # ws://geth:8546
  ETH_CHAIN_ID: "4"
  LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS: 0x514910771af9ca656af840dff83e8264ecf986ca # this was here ...
```

I port forward the k8s service and I see the Chainlink UI.

But what combination of the above should I use?

I have tried them all.

EDIT

In order to change the env vars, I ended up destroying the whole minikube env. Insane, and I have no idea why...

Now I get this in the logs

```
There are no accounts, creating a new account with the specified password
There are no P2P keys; creating a new key encrypted with given password
There are no OCR keys; creating a new key encrypted with given password
2022-09-02T10:22:50Z [INFO]  API exposed for user API_EMAIL=admin@admin.com     cmd/local_client.go:122 
2022-09-02T10:23:32Z [INFO]  POST /sessions                                     web/router.go:433                body={"email":"admin@admin.com","password":"*REDACTED*"} clientIP=127.0.0.1 errors=Error #01: Invalid email
 latency=4.918708ms method=POST path=/sessions servedAt=2022-09-02 10:23:32 status=401
```

... so I still cannot log in in the GUI. It is frustrating

**EDIT**

This is what happens when the instructions are not clear...
The username was `API_EMAIL=admin@admin.com` and the password `API_LOGIN=admin` .
Now I can login...but surely gonna change them...

Comment: your login info won't let you in? admin@admin.com and admin as the password at localhost:6688?

Comment: yes I tried this and nothing [Your email or password is incorrect. Please try again]

Comment: Try check the container logs, to ensure the chainlink node initialized your api user+password correctly and is not hanging on any other task.

Comment: In the logs I see this "2022-09-02T09:38:09Z [INFO]  API exposed for user API_EMAIL=one@one.com         cmd/local_client.go:122", but this is a mail I tried in an earlier failed test installation. I removed both chainlink and postgres from k8s , deleted any PV/PVC and reinstaleed. And I still see this in the logs. Why?